# How can I fix my performance issues with my socket listener class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

I'm new to TCP/IP programming. I have created a listener using Microsoft documentation and an example I found online.

I have created a program that listens on a port using the local IP.

When a message finally comes in, the program instantly hits 100% load and stays there, unfortunately I don't know a way of stopping it. I assume I have to use a `ManualResetEvent` but when I attempt to implement this, the webpage just doesn't load.

My implementation below is: (port is a random port if anyone was wondering)

```
public static class Listener 
{

    private const int bufferSize = 2048;
    private static byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    private static Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    public static void StartListening()
    {
        //Gets local machine IP address
        string ip = GetLocalIPAddress();
        //Creates the IPADDRESS
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
        //Creates a local end point for .Bind(xxx)
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 1322);
        Socket listenerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {

            //Binds to local machines IP with port 1322
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            //Places socket in a listening state
            listener.Listen(0);

            listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Throw exception

        }

    }

    private static void CloseSocket()
    {
        listener.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        listener.Close();
    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {


        //Socket casted to async state
        Socket listenerSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        try
        {
            //Try end accept
            listenerSocket = listener.EndAccept(ar);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Throw exception

        }
        //Receive data
        listenerSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack), listenerSocket);
        listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null); 
    }

    public static void ReadCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket listenerSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        int received = 0;
        try
        {
            //Amount of bytes that has been sent
            received = listenerSocket.EndReceive(ar);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            listener.Close();

        }
        //Create byte array for encoding
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[received];
        Array.Copy(buffer,bytes,received);
        string recievedMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
        if (received > 0)
        {
            //do task input
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(recievedMessage);
        }
        //work on this
        listenerSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0 , bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack), listenerSocket);



    }

    private static string GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Local IP Address Not Found!");
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

### Some issues

1. You are not passing the listener socket to the BeginAccept.

   ```
   listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
   ```

   and

   ```
   Socket listenerSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
   ```
2. Why do you read the `Socket listenerSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;`??
3. You construct a `listenerSocket` in the `StartListening` method, but you aren't using it.

### Bug

When you close the 'listener' (ServerClientSocket), you shoudn't call `BeginReceive` again. Just `return`.

When `received == 0` the socket is closed, so don't start `BeginReceive`. This is why it loops forever... The Begin/End receive returns directly with `received` == 0

```
public static void ReadCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket listenerSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

    int received = 0;
    try
    {
        //Amount of bytes that has been sent
        received = listenerSocket.EndReceive(ar);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        received = 0;
    }

    if(received == 0)
    {
        listener.Close();
        return;
    }

    //Create byte array for encoding
    byte[] bytes = new Byte[received];
    Array.Copy(buffer,bytes,received);
    string recievedMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    if (received > 0)
    {
        //do task input
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(recievedMessage);
    }
    //work on this
    listenerSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0 , bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack), listenerSocket);
}
```

### Note

TCP/IP sockets are streaming sockets, so you **never** know if you received a complete packet or even two. You need to know that you have a complete message received. A PreLength protocol is used often. Write a value that represents the amount of data that is following.

Comment: I just got home, I will eat then look at it, maybe later or tomorrow. Thank you for posting an answer. I will update. And to mention, I call 'startlistening' else where, sorry for not saying. And I shouldnt construct a socket in startlistening, i forgot to remove it from previous debugging etc.

Comment: @NewCallum the biggest problem you are going to have is the thing Jeron mentioned in his NOTE at the bottom. You must create a protocol for messages over the received data. 1 Send call can and often will take 2 or more Receive calls to get the data. Also 2 send calls can be merged into a single Receive call on the other end. Please read this artice on [Message Framing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that article helped thanks, also the issues you presented gave me ideas to fix my issue and the note also. Thanks for your help it now works like a dream (assuming when I fully test it, it handles it).

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are passing 0 as an argument for the Socket.Listen method, not sure if this is what causes the problem but its worth trying to change this to like 100

```
public void Listen(int backlog)
```

int backlog: The maximum length of the pending connections queue.

msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.net.sockets.socket.listen(v=vs.110).aspx